# my vwp not authorized, does it affect get to canada

Tags: usa, canada, us-visa-waiver-program, visa-refusals, land-borders

I have a passport. And I want to go to the USA, but my ESTA was denied because I have previously been denied a visa, so I want first go to Canada (because there I don't need ESTA or visa to travel) and from Canada go to USA by land. If my VWP is not authorized, does it affect getting to Canada? And then from Canada to USA?

It is written on vwp site:

> If you are a citizen of a country that participates in the Visa Waiver Program (VWP), and you enter the U.S. by land from Mexico or Canada, you are only required to complete the paper I-94W form at the land border crossing. ESTA is currently required for air and cruise ship travel only.

Comment: If your visa was denied previously, what makes you think taking a different route will change things..?

Comment: Please update your question with more details (not in the comments) - what passport, where you're trying to go, why your VWP was not authorized and so on. You realise there are borders between USA and Canada too so you still need visas.

Answer (score 5):

You are a national of Hungary and wish to travel to the United States, but your ESTA application to travel to the US under the Visa Waiver Program was denied because you have been previously denied a US visa.

According to the US Customs and Border Protection, [if your application for an ESTA was denied, you must get a visa if you wish to travel to the United States](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1074/~/esta-application-denied). It does not matter if you enter by land, sea or air, or via Canada, or what the purpose of your visit is.

The only exception to this is if you had applied with a passport number that was lost or stolen. In this case, you would need to replace the passport and reapply for the ESTA with the new passport number. But this exception does not apply to your circumstances.

Note also that Canada is not the United States and has [its own requirements for traveling there](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp?country=Hungary). Your status in the US has little bearing on whether you can enter Canada, but even if you are admitted to Canada you still will need a visa to enter the US.

Comment: Yes, but you still need the visa, because you have been previously denied, and they will see that when they scan your passport at the port of entry.